# Motivating mathematics(particularly algebraic number theory) through historical problems

Tags: reference-request, ho.history-overview, algebraic-number-theory

Most mathematical textbooks start a subject by going backwards, historically. They will define the terms that were invented to solve a problem in their polished form and then use these definitions and structures to solve a problem towards the end of the book, if at all. This is conceptually clear but often obscures motivation.

One glaring example of this is Galois theory. The original solution of the problem progressed through steps that barely resemble the final product. While some motivation is given, I have not found any book that goes through the historical steps that led to galois theory.

I would like any articles or books that motivate subjects through their historical roots/problems. I think what I am really asking for is a book/article that focuses on problems used to generate theory rather than the construction of a general theory that is later used to solve problems. For instance, I would like a book/article that explains what Lame's approach to fermat's last theorem was and how it failed and led to ideals.

I am particularly interested in books that focus on algebraic number theory, but other fields are very welcome too.

Edit: Thanks for the comment, I forgot to mention that it is crossposted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/924761/motivating-mathematicsparticularly-algebraic-number-theory-through-historical)

Comment: [Crossposted](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/924761/462) at MSE. Already has two answers there.

Comment: I found the books H.M. Edward:"Fermat's Last Theorem", Cox: "Primes of the Form x²+ny²" and Cohn: "Introduction to the construction of Class Fields" very nice and good.

Comment: I disagree with those who closed the question. I second for the Edwards book. Books like this are rare and useful, and certainly relevant to those doing "research mathematics".

Comment: I feel that a split of "Questions" into strictly mathematical, and the other more general, educational, philosophical (:-), etc., is long overdue. Perhaps we could have the less strictly mathematical q's in *meta*, together with entertainment like anecdotes, trivia, mathematical news, even history, etc.

Comment: On my point of view history of mathematics is a part of mathematics, and it does not have to be separated. Same applies to the questions about math literature (of graduate+ level). What is wrong with placing such questions here ?

Comment: I warmly second @Alexandre's comments and strongly disagree with those of Włodzimierz. The tragedy of Evariste Galois is part of the hagiography of mathematics and yet the subject that is taught nowadays bearing his name bears little resemblance to what he actually did. So in this case above all we should know more about the connection between the two.